# How to get the correct aggregate number if there are duplicates in each group by category

Tags: sql

I have a question in SQL like this:

For example, I have a fact table Users like this:

```
User_id    Device
   1         PC
   1         Mobile
   2         PC
   3         Mobile
  ...         ...
```

And After I summarize the fact table by query like:

```
select Device, count(distinct User_id) as count from Users;
```

I will get something like:

```
Device    Count
  PC       200
Mobile     100
```

The count of users for PC or Mobile separately is correct. However, the total sum for PC and Mobile is wrong because there are duplicate `user_id` in each device. Here, I will get 300 but may be the correct number is 250 because there are 50 users used both PC and Mobile.

Please help me with a SQL to get the correct number or may be a solution in other way like `Python`, `R` or `Hadoop`.

Thanks in advance for you Help.

Comment: What do you mean ? if there are 100 pc only users, 100 mobile only user, and 100 both pc and mobile, then what are the number you would like to see ? 100 i suppose ?

Answer (score 1):

What number do you want to get?

If you want one row per use, you need to decide which you want.  Perhaps:

```
select min_device_id, count(*)
from (select user_id, min(device_id) as min_device_id
      from users
      group by user_id
     ) u
group by min_device_id;
```

Another possibility is to get all combinations of devices and count each one separately:

```
select devices, count(*)
from (select user_id,
             (select distinct device_id + ','
              from users u
              where u2.user_id = u.user_id
              for xml path ('')
             ) as devices
      from (select distinct user_id from users) u
     ) u
group by devices;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want two things. (1) You want to see how many users use PC and how many use Mobile, which you've done with your query, and (2) you want to see how many users use either PC or Mobile. Since these sets overlap, you can't just sum the count records from your table. So just compute them separately.

Query 1 (you already have this):

```
select Device, count(distinct user_id) as count
    from Users
    group by Device
```

Query 2:

```
select count(distinct user_id)
    from Users
    where Device in ('PC','Mobile')
```